# Stripe Checkout session redirection fails when I deployed my app to Azure kubernetes cluster

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, stripe-payments, azure-aks

For some reason stripe checkout redirection doesn't work when I deployed my web app to azure Kubernetes cluster, I tested the app both locally and when running in a docker container and it worked fine. but when deployed, I tried testing the payment flow(pressing the pay btn) but there is no redirection to a stripe session.

the web app is a nodejs app with stripe redirection to handle the payment.
This is my docker file it is pretty simple and straight forward:
`FROM node:16`
`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`
`COPY package*.json ./`
`RUN npm install`
`COPY . .`
`EXPOSE 8080`
`CMD [ "npm", "start" ]`

I checked the pod's logs and the app runs as expected but when clicking on the pay button there is no redirection to the stripe session it stays on the same page.

I have added both the public and the private keys to my env variables file.
Not sure what I'm missing here.

Checkout endpoint:

```
app.post('/checkout', setCurrentUser, async (req, res) => {
  const customer = req.user
  const { product, customerID } = req.body
  const price = productToPriceMap[product]
  try {
    const session = await Stripe.createCheckoutSession(customerID, price)
   {
    customer.plan = "Futurist"
    customer.hasTrial = false
    customer.endDate= aYearFromNow.setFullYear(aYearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
    customer.save()
    res.send({
      sessionId: session.id
    })
    console.log(session)
    console.log("Upgrading user ....")
    await creat_offline_subscription(customer.email,customer.endDate)

  }
  console.log(session)

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400)
    return res.send({
      error: {
        message: e.message
      }
    })
  }

})
```

checkout btn trigger:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const publishableKey = 'public key here'

  const stripe = Stripe(
    publishableKey)
  const checkoutButton = $('#checkout-button')

  checkoutButton.click(function () {
    const product = $("input[name='product']:checked").val()

    fetch('/checkout', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'email': customer.email
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        product,
        customerID: customer.billingID
      })
    })
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then(({ sessionId }) => stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId }))
  })
```

I get in network tap when clicking the pay btn:

```
Fetch failed loading: POST "https://myapp.example/checkout".
(anonymous) @   account.js:12
dispatch    @   code.jquery.com/jque…3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
v.handle    @   code.jquery.com/jque…3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
```

Comment: Have you checked brower console? the network tab might tell you more about queries and responses, while the console itself might give us some insights on what's going on/was there anything failing to run? Maybe some headers issues? cors?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail regarding the issue you're facing other than 'doesn't work'.

Comment: I just get "XHR finished loading: POST "https://m.stripe.com/6" in console . when pressing the pay btn.

Comment: @JonathanSteele yep, sorry that wasn't clear enough I updated the description. but what I mean is the normal flow would be to press the pay btn stripe calls stripe api and creates a checkout session for the user to fill in card data. that doesn’t happen, what happens instead is on btn click the page calls the stripe api i get "XHR finished loading: POST "m.stripe.com/6" in the console network tab and the page stays the same. no redirections

Comment: Can you share the actual code you use to create the session and redirect to Checkout?

Comment: @JonathanSteele, just updated the description

Comment: Is there evidence of the Checkout Session(s) being created, or errors, in your [account logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs)? Are you able to log the `result` JSON returned from your Express endpoint?

Comment: yes get the session object in logs

Comment: You need to add some error handling to your client-side function to catch any errors returned from your backend.

Comment: wrapped the call into a try fetch but it just shows « error 400 Bad Request », I thought this would be an HTTP/HTTPS type of error but I set the website with an SSL certificate and it runs on https. so that shouldn't be the issue. 
Issue is not solved but I moved past it and used a payment link instead.